# Magento : Add customer default billing address

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to import the customers into my new magento installation from an old site and want to set customer address as magento customer default billing address i hvae tried

```
$customer = $this->getCustomerModel();
$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$customer->addAddress($results[0]['address']); //this says trying to save invalide object
$address ->addAddress($results[0]['address']); //this says undefined method
```

$results[0]['address'] this field contains the street address i have also the city,state, zip,postcode

Any idea about how can i set my customer address as its default billing or shipping address..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I have found it with help of Anoop sir.

```
$_custom_address = array (
    'firstname' => 'Branko',
    'lastname' => 'Ajzele',
    'street' => array (
        '0' => 'Sample address part1',
        '1' => 'Sample address part2',
    ),
    'city' => 'Osijek',
    'region_id' => '',
    'region' => '',
    'postcode' => '31000',
    'country_id' => 'HR', /* Croatia */
    'telephone' => '0038531555444',
);
$customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
//$customAddress = new Mage_Customer_Model_Address();
$customAddress->setData($_custom_address)
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
try {
    $customAddress->save();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: aaand here's the link: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programatically-create-customer-and-order-in-magento-with-full-blown-one-page-checkout-process-under-the-hood/

Comment: How the same can achieved in m2?

Comment: @ravi do you know how set existing address as default billing and shipping address

Comment: @SunethKalhara Hi Suenth, unfortunately i stopped working on Magento, since I left there are major changes happened in the Magento ecosystem, I believe you should get in touch with someone having current knowledge of the platform